# Windows 7 dual boot with Debian Jessie

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, multi-boot, debian-jessie

I had debian jessie installed on a single hard drive, then i added 3 other hard drives just for storage purposes but I installed Windows 7 Home Premium on one of them. It was working fine until windows update corrupted my Windows drive, and upon trying to reinstall i deleted that partition on the drive. Then upon booting i get an error on the Debian drive saying "missing operating system". I could only reinstall windows by unplugging all but the desired drive, and now i still cannot boot Debian, but Windows will only boot properly with only its drive plugged in. I am trying to find a way to leave all 4 drives plugged in, and repair my Debian installation. Does anyone know what the problem could be booting with the other drives plugged in? and any way to repair Debian so that it will recognize the operating system alongside Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

Your safest way with the least headaches would be to install Win7 on one drive with all other drives disconnected. Then install Debian on the next drive with all other drives disconnected. That way the bootmgr of W7 and the Debian Grub do not get into each other's way.

For selecting an OS you go to the temporary BIOS boot order and select the disk with the OS you want.

Comment: I think i figured it out and it may be what your talking about, but when i installed windows it wiped grub from my MBR, and i tried to install a different linux distro on one of the free disks but for some reason that didnt work, but now i am going to try something called super grub disk, that supposedly i can boot into to reinstall grub to the MBR which should handle the booting issues. I will post an answer when i figure out what worked.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by downloading, and booting from, the boot-repair tool 
and that solved my boot issues by overwriting the MBR with grub instead of Windows boot loader